# MapStruct @Mapping(expression="java(...)")

Tags: java, mapping, expression, mapstruct

Is it possible to have a condition like an if-else or a Ternary Operator inside the

```
@Mapping(expression="java(...)")
```

I have a method that returns the last item of an ArrayList, but in case the list is empty it returns null. I need a condition, so in case I receive the item I can use it, or in case it is null it will map null.

```
public static MyObjectDetail getLastOne(MyObject myObject) {
    List<MyObjectDetail> details = myObject.getMyObjectDetails();
    if(details.isEmpty()) {
        return null;
    } else {
        return myObject.getLastDetail(myObject);
    }
}
```

This is the @Mapping that I currently use and it works fine if the list is not empty.

```
@Mapping(expression = "java(MyObjectDetailMapper.getLastOne(myObject).getNumber())", target = "number"),
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Solution:

```
@Mapping(expression = "java(null == MyObjectDetailMapper.getLastOne(myObject) ? null : MyObjectDetailMapper.getLastOne(myObject).getNumber())", target = "number"),
```

[Mapping expression documentation](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#expressions)